# Copy a file to a remote computer

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, openstack, remote-desktop, copy-item

I have made two instances on sky-high; **cl1** and **srv1**. I am trying to copy a folder from **cl1** to **srv1**. I can use the command

`Enter-PSSession -Credential $cred IP_ADD_SRV1`

from **cl1** to get into **srv1**. I have been looking at the help site for [copy-item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1) and found this command called *Copy a file to a remote computer*. Is this right? The command is

`$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server01" -Credential "Contoso\User01"`

`Copy-Item "D:\Folder001\test.log" -Destination "C:\Folder001_Copy\" -ToSession $Session`

My questions are:

- Is the ComputerName just the name I called them on my Microsoft Remote Desktop?
- And what do I put as the credential?
- My problem is that the path for the two folders I want to copy are almost the same. Someone told me I need to use the UNC path. Do I need to use this
  both at the copy-item and destination? I am new to this, but does
  this look right for the UNC path: **\\cl1\C$\Users\Admin\Test**. ?

Comment: See [Use PowerShell Copy-Item to File Transfer Over WinRM](https://blog.ipswitch.com/use-powershell-copy-item-cmdlet-transfer-files-winrm)

Comment: Does this really need to be tagged with `[openstack]`?  I don't see the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy a file or folder from a pc to a **remote** machine in several ways.

- **A 'Normal' copy (not using a Session object)**

if the pc you are logged into is called `cl1` and the file is on that computer (source), you need to specify the **Destination** in UNC format:

```
Copy-Item -Path 'C:\SourceFolder\TheFileToCopy.txt' -Destination '\\srv1\c$\DestinationFolder'
```

If however the file is on the remote machine and you need to copy that **TO** the machine you're logged into, then the **Source** should be in UNC format:

```
Copy-Item -Path '\\srv1\c$\TheFileToCopy.txt' -Destination 'C:\DestinationFolder'
```

- **Using the Session object**

if the pc you are logged into is called `cl1` and the file is on that computer (source) and you have established a session using `$session = New-PSSession –ComputerName srv1` to the remote machine, then you need to specify both the Path and Destination parameters as LOCAL paths:

```
Copy-Item -Path 'C:\SourceFolder\TheFileToCopy.txt' -Destination 'C:\DestinationFolder' -ToSession $session
```

<sup>A Credential object contains user name and (encrypted) password to use to authenticate to the remote machine. Use the `Get-Credential` cmdlet for that</sup>

---

It seems you want to copy a directory from a source on computer `Cl1` to a path on the remote server `srv1`.
From your comments, I see that the **source** is `C:\Users\Admin\Test` (that is the LOCAL path of the computer you are logged in to, i.e. `Cl1`) and that the **destination** would be `C:\Users\Admin\Backup` on the REMOTE machine.
That is why you need to use the UNC format for the destination path, `C:\Users\Admin\Backup` --> `\\srv1\C$\Users\Admin\Backup`.

Using the servers name needs DNS to be set up properly, so you can also use the IP address of that server instead of its name. Suppose that the server has IP `10.212.141.129`, the UNC path for the destination would then become `\\10.212.141.129\C$\Users\Admin\Backup`.

However.. You are targetting the so-called [Administrative Share](https://networkencyclopedia.com/administrative-share/) (`C$`), and for that you need to have permissions. Also you are targetting a user folder for user Admin (which is user Admin on the **remote** machine, and that is not the same one as the Administrator on **your** computer.
Therefore, it is quite possible you do not have access permissions on the target folder.
You can give yourself permissions (if you know the correct credentials of course) by adding parameter `-Credential $cred` to the Copy-Item cmdlet. Such a credentials object is easily obtained by using

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Please enter Domain Admin credentials"
```

For `Copy-Item` to be able to copy something to somewhere, you must make sure the destination path exists.
Try to navigate in File Explorer to that remote path using the same UNC naming convention.

If for instance the path `\\srv1\C$\Users\Admin` exists, but there is no folder `Backup`, (and you have permissions to do so), create that folder, either from within Explorer, or in PowerShell:

```
if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath '\\srv1\C$\Users\Admin\Backup' -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path '\\srv1\C$\Users\Admin\Backup' -ItemType Directory
}
```

Next, you should be able to copy all files and subfolders from the source directory to that destination using

```
Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Users\Admin\Test' -Destination '\\srv1\C$\Users\Admin\Backup' -Recurse  # -Credential $cred # can go here
# local source on cl1  ^^^^                              ^^^^ to remote destination on srv1
```

Of course, you can also use the **Session** method I've described earlier., where in that case you should use local pathnames (C:\whatever) and don't need UNC paths, because the $session object takes care of that for you.

<sup>It *could* be that on the destination server, there is a share set-up for you that resides somewhere else. For instance a folder `X:\Students\Course1\Output` and that path has been shared as `StudentMaterial$`.
If this might be the case (ask your teacher) you can set the destination as `\\srv1\StudentMaterial$` and you do not need to go all the way via the Administrative Share.</sup>

Hope this explains some more

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!!
I tried the `normal´ copy, but got the error message: Copy-Item: The network path was not found. : '\\srvr1\c$\Users\Admin\Test'.

Is it possible to use the IP address instead of srv1 in the command?

Comment: @Maria.A The IP address is also fine. Are you sure the path exists an you have access (users\admin)...

Comment: I really appreciate your help here! I have tried:

`Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Users\Admin\Test' -Destination '\\srv1\c$\C:\Users\Admin\Backup'`     
   
`Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Users\Admin\Test' -Destination '\\srv1\c$\Users\Admin\Backup'`     
   
`Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Users\Admin\Test' -Destination '\\192.168.111.182\c$\Users\Admin\Backup'`    
   
`Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Users\Admin\Test' -Destination '\\10.212.141.129\c$\Users\Admin\Backup'`     
  
...but I still get the same error... I use the run as administrator on the cl1 when I try the commands.

Comment: Do I need to use the `Enter-PSSession -Credential $cred IP_ADD_SRV1` command first?

Comment: @Maria.A SO does not allow many comments, so I have added more explanation to the answer